# Dibujar figuras en Java

Tags: java, java-awt

Como puedo dibujar una estrella en java? La parte que me confunde es el de las coordenadas en g.drawline debido a que no entiendo en que orden se escriben y como darme una idea de las coordenadas correctas para dibujar una estrella.

Esto es lo que llevo de mi código.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


class Pantalla extends Frame{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
Pantalla p=new Pantalla();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"bienvenido sistema de algo");
}
public Pantalla()
{
this.setSize(1600,900);
setBackground(new Color(200,0,180));
this.setVisible(true);
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0));
g.drawString("Hola",400,100);
g.drawLine(400,100,800,100);
g.drawLine(500,150,450,200);
g.drawLine(500,150,550,200);
g.drawLine(350,100,200,250);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola aunque estas usando el metodo drawLine otra alternativa seria usar drawPolygon el cual es un metodo al cual les pasas directamente las coordenadas y cantidad de puntos.

Ejemplo para obtener las coordenas te puedes basar un plano como la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {


    public MainWindow()
    {
        setBounds(0, 0, 300, 300);
        setBackground(new Color(200,0,180));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        int[] coordenadasX={130,150,210,160,180,130,80,100,50,110};
        int[] coordenadasY={20,90,90,130,200,160,200,130,90,90};
        int nPuntos=10;

        g.drawPolygon(coordenadasX, coordenadasY, nPuntos);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainWindow ventana=new MainWindow();
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

Para mas informacion sobre el metodo drawPolygon https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolygon-int:A-int:A-int-

Answer (score 2):

Lado superior-izquierdo es el punto (0,0), es decir el punto inicial

> **no entiendo en que orden se escriben?**

para responder tu pregunta citare un
ejemplo:

> g.drawLine(iniX,iniY,finX,finY);
>
> g.drawLine(400,100,100,200);
>
> para dibujar una linea finita se necesita 2 puntos por lo tanto:
>
> p1=(400,100) y p2=(100,200)

entonces esa instruccion dibujara algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo hacer un polígono por programación y luego pintarlo:

```
Polygon poligono = new Polygon();

//Numero de puntas del poligono
int puntas = 5;
//Distancia de la punta hasta centro del poligono
double radioExterior = 40;
//Distancia del valle interior hasta el centro
double radioInterior = 20;
//Coordenadas en el frame para del centro del poligono
double xCentro = getWidth()/2, yCentro = getHeight()/2;
//Inclinacion inicial si no queremos que la punta este en angulo 0
double inclinacionPrimeraPunta = Math.PI;//Punta hacia arriba

//Calculamos los puntos por trigonometria
double anguloEntreVertices = Math.PI/puntas;
for(int i = 0; i < puntas*2; i++){
    //Vamos alternando entre los radios de punta y valle
    double r = (i%2 == 0)?radioExterior:radioInterior;
    double a = i*anguloEntreVertices + inclinacionPrimeraPunta;
    //Añadimos el nuevo punto al poligono
    poligono.addPoint(
        //Coordenada X
        (int)(r*Math.sin(a) + xCentro),
        //Coordenada Y
        (int)(r*Math.cos(a) + yCentro));
}

//Pintamos el poligono
g.drawPolygon(poligono);
```

Así se puede cambiar fácilmente el tamaño, posición, inclinación, hacer copias, etc... Imagina calcular a mano los puntos para 5 estrellas de 8 puntas por ejemplo... una locura.

Tal cual está ahora el centro del polígono (con las coordenadas relativas a la anchura y altura del frame) puedes probar a cambiar el tamaño de la ventana y verás una bonita estrella moviéndose.

Para verlo mejor te sugiero que limpies la pantalla al principio del método con `fillRect` o se quedará pintado lo anterior.

Te adjunto la salida de añadir éste código al tuyo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola AwesOmeM4n, no se si seguirás por aquí. Me interesa tu respuesta. Sería posible que publicaras la clase Polygon ? gracias

Comment: @Joseba la clase usada en el ejemplo es la nativa de Java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html Un saludo.