# Rellenar una figura en Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Como puedo rellenar la figura que dibuje en java cuando hice la figura con solo g.drawLine?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


class Corazon extends Frame{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      Corazon p=new Corazon();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bienvenido al Dibujo de un corazon");
   }
   public Corazon()
   {
      this.setSize(1600,900);
      setBackground(new Color(0,0,150));
      this.setVisible(true);
   }
   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0));
      g.drawString("Stephanie B. Orihuela",400,100);
      g.drawLine(630,140,600,140);
      g.drawLine(600,140,570,170);
      g.drawLine(570,170,570,190);
      g.drawLine(570,190,590,210);
      g.drawLine(590,210,640,250);
      g.drawLine(640,250,690,210);
      g.drawLine(690,210,710,190);
      g.drawLine(710,190,710,170);
      g.drawLine(710,170,690,140);
      g.drawLine(690,140,660,140);
      g.drawLine(660,140,640,170);
      g.drawLine(640,170,630,140);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar el método `fillPolygon`. En [tu otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48068/dibujar-figuras-en-java) te recomendabamos que usaras polilineas o poligonos en vez de rectas sueltas. Incluso en tu otra pregunta te recomendaba que primero programaras las formas por programación ya que son mucho más flexibles que definirlas punto a punto.

Si insistes en hacerlo punto a punto simplemente pasa dos arrays de enteros (uno para X y otro para Y como te decía @ReneGarnica) y el numero de puntos totales al método `fillPolygon(int[] x, int[]y, int n)`

Y otra recomendación: deberías llamar al método `super.paint(g)` dentro del método que sobreescribes si no quieres perder lo que hace la super clase (por ejemplo limpiar el frame cuando haya que repintar.

Comment: La razón de hacerla con solo rectas es por que la maestra asi lo quiere :/

Comment: No puedes rellenarlo con rectas, necesitas una forma.